# How to create a custom field in Magento 2 user registration?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, save, registration

I want to create a custom input field in Magento 2 user registration page and save this field in database. Can you help me ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if it's working or not for you.

Answer (score 2):

For add custom field in database create `InstallSchema.php` file

**=> app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallSchema.php :**

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $eavTable = $installer->getTable('customer_entity');
        $columns = [
            'mobile' => [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 20,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'comment' => 'mobile',
            ],
            //which field you want to create
        ];

        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

Create Layout file :

**=> app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">CompanyName_ModuleName::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
         </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Now, get all code from `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` file and create your view.phtml file in your extension `/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`

Then, add field in phtml file where you want to add.

For, Record save you can use observer :

First, add events.xml for execute observer file :

**=> app/code/etc/events.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after">
        <observer name="customer_register_success" instance="CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer\Savecustomer" />
    </event>

 </config>
```

Now, create observer file and add your code logic which you want to save :

**=> app/code/Observer/Savecustomer.php :**

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
class Savecustomer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
           ....................
           // Your code logic
           .................... 
    }
}
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Happy Coding..!! :)

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/view.phtml i did'nt find this file

Comment: I updated path in my answer. You can check it.

Comment: ok, i try to find this

Comment: Sure :) Let me know if  any issue will generate.

Comment: sure i will inform

Comment: please accept and upvote answer if it's working. So, other user can use this code.

Comment: I am working on this. once i complete, i will accept this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76485/discussion-between-mohd-hasan-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).